# Stackoverflow MediaPlayer Android Seekbar

Tags: android, media-player, stack-overflow, seekbar

i am having strange issue in one of my app in the play store. The problem is i cannot replicate the issue at all. Here is my play store log cat. Any help or thoughts would be much appreciated. There is like 9 reports. There are more than 10000 active users.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.os.Message.obtain(Message.java:236)
at android.os.Handler.obtainMessage(Handler.java:247)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.postEventFromNative(MediaPlayer.java:1760)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration(Native Method)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore.PlayerActivity$10.onProgressChanged(PlayerActivity.java:300)
at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:609)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:621)
at android.widget.ProgressBar.setMax(ProgressBar.java:775)
at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.setMax(AbsSeekBar.java:180)
at com.peshal....
```

Here is the code for PlayerActivity.java

```
package com.peshal.nepalisongsandmore;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;


public class PlayerActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayerSingleton.mediaPlayer;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    Button play;
    Button forward;
    Button rewind;
    Button pause;
    Button previous;
    Button next;
    ImageView img; 
    SeekBar seekBar;
    String mediaType;
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;
    TextView textView;
int position;
ArrayList<String> urls;
String url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.equalizer_anim);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songinfo);

    //  new LoadEqualizer().execute();
         if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
             mediaPlayer.reset();
         }

        mediaType = getIntent().getExtras().getString("mediaType");
        if(mediaType.equals("songs")) {
        position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
        urls = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("urls");
        }
        else if(mediaType.equals("radios")) {
            url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("radioUrl");
            //radioName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("radioName");
        }


        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        forward = (Button)findViewById(R.id.forward);
        rewind = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rewind);
        pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
        previous =(Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rewind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        textView.setText("Buffering..");
        playMusic();

    }



    public void playMusic() {
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer1), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer2), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer3), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer4), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer5), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer6), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer7), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer8), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer9), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer10), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer11), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer12), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer13), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer14), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer15), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer16), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer17), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer18), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer19), 50);
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.equalizer20), 50);
        frameAnimation.setOneShot(false); 
        img.setBackgroundDrawable(frameAnimation);
        frameAnimation.start();
        frameAnimation.stop();

         mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
         try {
             if(mediaType.equals("songs")) {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urls.get(position));
             }
             else if (mediaType.equals("radios")) {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
             }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                frameAnimation.start();
                if (mediaType.equals("songs")) {

                rewind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                forward.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                previous.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            }
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setText("");
            }

        });



        pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                frameAnimation.stop();
                play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rewind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

        });
        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.start();    
                frameAnimation.start();
                play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (mediaType.equals("songs")) {
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                rewind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                forward.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

        });
        forward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + 1000);

            }

        });
        previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position==0) {
                position = urls.size() -2;
                }
                else {
                    position = position-2;
                }
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rewind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getNextTrack();

            }

        });
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rewind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                forward.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getNextTrack();

            }

        });
        rewind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - 1000);

            }

        });


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                frameAnimation.stop();

                if(mediaType.equals("songs")) {
                    getNextTrack();

            }
            }

        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener(){
            int state;

            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                state = tm.getCallState();
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK|| state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    new CallHandler().execute();
                }
            }

        });


        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                if(fromUser){               
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

        });

    }

    Intent intent;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(MediaPlayerSingleton.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerActivity.class);     
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent,0);
            NotificationCompat.Builder noti =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)
                    .setContentTitle("Nepali Music And more")
                    .setContentText("Playing");
        noti.setContentIntent(pIntent);
        noti.setAutoCancel(true);
        noti.setOngoing(true);
         Notification notification = noti.getNotification();


            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (notificationManager!=null) {
        notificationManager.cancel(1);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }



    public void getNextTrack() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isLooping()||mediaPlayer.isLooping()) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        if(position!=(urls.size()-1)) {
            position = position + 1;
        }
        else{
            position=0;
        }
        playMusic();
    }
public class CallHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("New asynctask started", " Call handler");
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        while(tm.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK|| tm.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d("asynctask finished", " Call handler");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: And where's the code?

Comment: Try to remove `seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration())` this might be the cause of problem according to logcat

Comment: I really need the setMax for the setOnBufferingUpdate to work. Otherwise it will nor work properly. Entire seekbars length depend on that. Every songs have different lengths. Also the setmax is only trigerred once per song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());` from `onProgressChanged` - it doesn't need to be there, you should have accurate duration in the `onPrepared` callback, no need to set it again in other callbacks

UPDATE:

At least you need to remove it from `onProgressChanged` call, because changing `SeekBar` max value can change progress position and trigger `onProgressChanged` again. If you really need to call `setMax` - make `onProgressChanged` schedule on the UI thread - you can use `post(Runnable)`

Comment: Hi msh, Thanks for you suggestions, removing that will actually break more things than solving the issue, I just tried that, when i remove the line the onProgressChanged callback doesn't work properly, it takes forever to seek to that position and sometimes, onCompletion is invoked. Pretty much every code is there for a reason. I was thinking may be doing something differently would solve the issue. I am thinking that a lot of users of my app are from Nepal and the internet connection is not great there. Can that be the reason?

Comment: I don't really understand how removing setMax can break anything, but at least you need to remove it from onProgressChanged, because changing SeekBar max value can change progress position and trigger onProgressChanged again. If you really need to call setMax - make onProgressChanged schedule it the UI thread - you can use post(Runnable)